# Rails 3 - lib uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::STATES

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created one file named br_states.rb in lib/ in the my rails 3 project, but when I call States in my view I received this error message:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::STATES
```

I already set autoload_path in my application.rb to load lib folder, but yet no works.
`config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "lib")`

This is my code: https://gist.github.com/1822459

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to provide a namespace for that constant. I think Rails's auto-loader can't figure out that your `STATES` constant is defined in a file called `br_states.rb`:

```
# lib/states.rb
module States
  BRAZIL = [
    # ...
  ]
end
```

I also suggest following gg_s's answer:

```
# new.html.erb
<%= adr.select :state, options_for_select(States::BRAZIL), :label => "Estado", :required => true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

```
<%= adr.select :state, options_for_select(STATES), :label => "Estado", :required => true %>
```

Note that that Rails will use each two-element array like this: `[option text, option value]`, meaning your form's `select` will be full of "AC", "AL", ... and will submit "Acre", "Alagoas",...

I assume you want it to show the full text and return the abbreviation. Switch the values in your STATES array:

```
STATES = [[ "Acre",     "AC" ],
          [ "Alagoas",  "AL" ],
          [ "Amazonas", "AM" ],
          [ "Amapá",    "AP" ],
          # and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the abbreviations file, line 18 is missing a set of double quotes. That probably isn't the source of this particular problem, but it will cause problems for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that your filename didn't match your class name. If you changed your file name from "br_states.rb" -> "states.rb" then rails autoloading would have been able to resolve the "STATES" constant correctly. Check this article out which explains autoloading in more detail. http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/